# Mean curvature of the pseudosphere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let $x(v,u) = sech(v) sin(u)$,  $y(v,u) = sech(v) cos(u)$, $z(v,u) = v - tanh(v)$ the equations of a pseudosphere. I computed its mean curvature and got $\frac{Csch(v) - Sinh(v)}{2}$, although I found that Wolfram reports the opposite value of my mean curvature, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudosphere.html).

I computed my mean curvature summing the two principal curvatures (which I got as eigenvalues of Weingarten matrix) and dividing by two. I got the same exact principal curvatures reported in the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796002/gaussian-curvature-of-a-pseudosphere). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principal curvatures, and therefore mean curvature, change sign under change of orientation; presumably you and Wolfram have chosen opposite normal vectors. (Gaussian curvature is independent of orientation, of course.)